# Physical interpretation of spinor parameter $\epsilon$ in supersymmetry

Tags: special-relativity, supersymmetry, representation-theory, spinors

Studying supersymmetry, I came across the introduction of the idea of SUSY field variations involving spinor parameters $\epsilon_{\alpha}$ under which actions must be invariant. This spinor parameter transforms a scalar field into a fermion via:
$$\delta(\epsilon) \phi(x) = \bar{\epsilon} \psi(x)$$

So I'm struggling with the physical interpretation of $\epsilon$. Is this a matrix and how does it look like? Or has it another representation?

Comment: Do you understand how $\psi$ is represented?

Comment: Isn't $\psi$ just a column vector?

Comment: Yes. So what does $\bar\epsilon$ have to be to make the variation be a scalar?

Comment: A row vector? So $\epsilon$ is also a column vector so $\bar{\epsilon}$ is a row vector?

Comment: That’s my understanding.